# Нестандартная сетка

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Как сделать такую сетку?
Пытаюсь через grid, но не все равно не получается.
Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3,1fr) / repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper div{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4){
  grid-row: 2/4; 
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2){
  grid-column: 2/4;  
  grid-row: 1/3;  
}

.wrapper div:last-child{
  grid-column: 3/5;  
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!